# cheapest way to set up an "app service environment" (ase) for a dev environment?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm trying to set up an App Service Environment (ASE) for basic test purposes in my Azure Resource Group so I can get familiar with it's structure and functionality and how it integrates with a broader Azure solution.  The "ASE pricing details" blade shows pricing which appears to be pretty high:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2tv7cdetmi20ds/ase-pricing-details.png?dl=0

But Microsoft has a pricing page which appears to indicate a free option as well:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

I want to configure an ASE in my test Resource Group for the absolute minimum cost, free if possible. My organization currently has 3 Azure subsriptions and I have an additional Visual Studio Professional subscription through my organization with a balance of about $49. The "ASE pricing plan" image I included at the first url above doesn't show a free option. So can you advise on the steps I can follow to associate a free trial of ASE with my VS Pro subscription?  Or do I need to take a different approach for this?

Answer (score 2):

> So can you advise on the steps I can follow to associate a free trial of ASE with my VS Pro subscription?

Unfortunately, there is no free ASE service plan. We could get more information about ASE from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro). As ASE is designed for very high scale,Isolation and secure network access and High memory utilization. So that is why it is much more expensive.

> The Azure App Service Environment is an Azure App Service feature that provides a fully isolated and dedicated environment for securely running App Service apps at **high scale**.
>
> App Service environments (ASEs) are appropriate for application workloads that require:
>
> - **Very high scale**.
> - **Isolation and secure network access**.
> - **High memory utilization**.

---

> Or do I need to take a different approach for this?

As it is limited by budget, I don't think ASE is a good approach for you.
If you still want to get familiar with it's structure and functionality and how it integrates with a broader Azure solution. I recommand that you could learn more and more information about ASE firstly and with hour pay plan to do more exercise in limit hours.